# how to make fast execution of an await function written inside nested for loop

Tags: node.js, express, promise, async-await, callback

Maybe my question title is wrong. But I am explaining everything in body. My question is that I am hitting an API for student detail. That give multiple student records.

Response example

```
    {
                    "TotalRecords": "372",
                    "StudentName": "John Carter",
                    "StudentImage": "",
                    "AnotherKey": "Another Value",
                    "AnotherKey1": "Another Value1",
                    "ClassDetail": [
                        {"class":"5","rollnumber":"123"},
                        {"class":"6","rollnumber":"456"},
                        {"class":"7","rollnumber":"678"}
                    ],
                    "ChildCenterLocationList": [
                        {
                            "CenterLocationId": "4",
                            "CenterLocationName": "Stockton"
                        }
                    ]
                    
    },
    {
                    "TotalRecords": "372",
                    "StudentName": "John Luke",
                    "StudentImage": "",
                    "AnotherKey": "Another Value",
                    "AnotherKey1": "Another Value1",
                    "ClassDetail": [
                        {"class":"5","rollnumber":"123"},
                        {"class":"6","rollnumber":"456"},
                        {"class":"7","rollnumber":"678"}
                    ],
                    "ChildCenterLocationList": [
                        {
                            "CenterLocationId": "4",
                            "CenterLocationName": "Stockton"
                        }
                    ]
                    
    }
```

for that I wave written simple logic on my controller page

```
exports.GetChildsDetail = async function (req, res) {
try {
        
       let parms = [req.userId, req.query.Date];
       let spRes = await _dbContaxt.ExcuteQuery(StoredProcdureName, parms);
       if (spRes != null && spRes.length > 0) {
           //till now everything is good. I am getting the response properly as I mentioned above and sending it to client
        }
}


})
```

Now again the requirement came that you have to find the subject detail and mark sheet detail of each class for each student using rollnumber from ClassDetail key.

So ClassDetail key will be something like

```
"ClassDetail": [
                    {
                    "class":"5",
                    "rollnumber":"123",
                    "subjectDetail": [{'subject1detail'},{'subject1detail'},{'subject1detail'}]
                    "mrksheetDetail": [{'this is again an complex object'}]
                    },
                    {
                    "class":"6",
                    "rollnumber":"456",
                    "subjectDetail": [{'subject1detail'},{'subject1detail'},{'subject1detail'}]
                    "mrksheetDetail": [{'this is again an complex object'}]
                    }
                    {
                    "class":"7",
                    "rollnumber":"678",
                    "subjectDetail": [{'subject1detail'},{'subject1detail'},{'subject1detail'}]
                    "mrksheetDetail": [{'this is again an complex object'}]
                    }
               ]
```

So again I was doing it as I did above

```
exports.GetChildsDetail = async function (req, res) {
    try {
            
           let parms = [req.userId, req.query.Date];
           let spRes = await _dbContaxt.ExcuteQuery(StoredProcdureName, parms);
           if (spRes != null && spRes.length > 0) {
               for (var clients of spRes.ResData) {
                 let arrSubCodes = [];
                  for (var authList of clients.ClassDetail) {
                   let parms1 = [req.userId, authList.rollnumber, req.query.Date];
                        let spRes1 = await _dbContaxt.ExcuteQuery(_StoredProcedureForSubject, parms1);
                      if (spRes1 != null && spRes1.length > 0) {
                       arrSubCodes.push(singleData1.ResData.SubjectDetail)
                      }
                  }
                   clients.subjectDetail= arrSubCodes;
               }
            }
    }
    
    
    })
```

Result is coming But it takes too much time almost 2 mins. I have only 10 students. So I tried another way it faster but it works only for last rollnumber of loop. The code is after calling the main loop.

```
if (spRes != null && spRes.length > 0) {
await Promise.all( spRes.ResData.map(async (item) => {
    
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       for (var i in item.ClassDetail) {
        let parms2 = [req.userId, item.ClassDetail[i].rollnumber];
         _dbContaxt.ExcuteQuery(_dbHelper._StoredProcedureForSubject, parms2).then(spRes1=>{
             if (spRes1 != null && spRes1.length > 0) {
                item.ClassDetail[i].subjectDetail= spRes1.ResData;
                resolve()
             }
          })
       }
   })

 }))
}
```

This code works good for last rollnumber only. If I have multiple records in ClassDetail key then it works only for the last record.

Comment: Do not use `new Promise`! You are getting the wrong result because you are calling `resolve()` from the first iteration. Just keep the inner loop with `async`/`await`.

Comment: @Bergi will you please show me that code.

Comment: @Bergi Thank you so much. I have done same as you said. Till now it is working fine.

Comment: Cool, props to you for figuring this out yourself! You can [post it as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) to signal the question is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried as @[bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi) says and its working fine

```
if (spRes != null && spRes.length > 0) {
await Promise.all( spRes.ResData.map(async (item) => {
       for (var i in item.ClassDetail) {
        let parms2 = [req.userId, item.ClassDetail[i].rollnumber];
        let spRes1 = await _dbContaxt.ExcuteQuery(_dbHelper._StoredProcedureForSubject, parms2)
             if (spRes1 != null && spRes1.length > 0) {
                item.ClassDetail[i].subjectDetail= spRes1.ResData;
             }
       }
 }))
}
```

Comment: Why your functions needs to be using `await Promise.all` ? Can't you just have proper async await chain

Comment: It was making it too slow. takes almost 2 min even for 10 record of students